# 32 bit exe file will not run on a 64 bit computer

Tags: windows, 32-bit

I downloaded a bunch of exe files (for Ron Mak C compiler book) and tried to run the exe file from the command line and get the following error message:

> This version of xxx.exe file is not compatible with the version of Windows that you are running. Check your computers system information and contact the publisher.

This software is old, about the time Borland was around, and I'm using Windows 8.1. I thought that any 64 bit machine should run a 32 bit exe file.

Can I get this 32 bit software to run on my 64 bit machine?

Comment: there are several free C compilers for Windows.  http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite or with Cygwin - https://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 7):

It's likely that if the software is that old, then it's actually a 16-bit executable, not a 32-bit one.

64-Bit versions of windows cannot run 16-bit software.  Only the 32-bit versions can do that.

Comment: you got there first... GG my good sir

Comment: I actually ran across this recently with a hilariously old version of Quicken a customer was using, so it was fresh on my mind.  She even had the box, with a big red sticker that boldly proclaimed "Also works in Windows 95!!"

Comment: uh... wow. 95. um... that's... old

Answer (score 1):

if it's a 16bit software, that might be impossible to run on a 64bit Windows
if it's a 32bit, you still have the choice to run the compability troubleshooter and chose an older Windows which is closer to that **AGE** like rinning it like in windows 98 or XP
don't forget that most of old compilers require running them **as an administrator**